# Source database does not contain a recognizable Drupal version

Tags: drupal

I am migrating a Drupal 7 content database to Drupal8(drupal8 installed via bitnami).
While using phpMyAdmin. i keep receiving an error on import "Source database does not contain a recognizable Drupal version". Several solutions point to a table prefix(which my tables do not have). Additionally a few solutions are pointed towards the system table which is very confusing.
can someone please help me mitigate the issue. i am lost at exploring options other than identifying the issue in the database.

Comment: Are you using postgresql ? You need to set a database prefix on your d7 db.

Comment: Thank you Eric, I am using MySQL. Tried the bitnami Drupal 7 to just migrate to Drupal 8 and it failed. I am not sure why a Drupal 7 (with one site) installation(done on windows 10) will not migrate to Drupal 8(done on windows on same machine). Drush commands are complicating it further in windows. can you suggest any free tools to do an assessment of what is wrong with my Drupal 7 database. all works fine and perfect in Drupal 7.

Comment: The errors I am experiencing are ranging from   a)Drupal 8 Site upgrade button identifies the Drupal 7 database and after clicking review upgrade brings the original screen of Upgrade back. its cyclic in nature. using xdebug I found the only error..schema_version to be not of 7. that wasfixed and then the cyclic life of the upgrade button